# filter data From ansible_default_ipv4.macaddress

Tags: linux, ansible, jinja2

Dear community i ask for your help please.

I would create a playbook that will take a macaddress given in input and it should respect the `Unix` format. Then, if the address given respects the required format, another task will check if the given macaddress match an existed one in the hosts, **if it exists it will show `the interface related to that macaddress` if not the task will fail with an error message `"No interfaces found with mac address '$MACADDRESS'. Fatal error."`

here is what was done by me, i don't what should be done to achieve the goal:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "MACADDRESS"
      prompt: "mac address?(please use Unix format ex- 1a:2b:3c:4d:5e:6f )"
      private: no


  tasks:
    - name: check macaddresssyntax
      debug:
        msg: "{{ MACADDRESS | ansible.utils.hwaddr('unix') }}"
      register: mac_syntax
      failed_when: mac_syntax failed


    - name: check local mac
      debug:
        var: mac_syntax |intersect (ansible_facts['default_ipv4']|selectattr('macaddress') | map(attribute='interface')|list)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't normally register the result of a `debug` task (because it's not useful). If you want to fail when someone enters an invalid MAC address, use the `fail` task:

   ```
   - name: check mac address syntax
     fail:
         msg: "Invalid mac address syntax"
     when: not MACADDRESS|ansible.utils.hwaddr('unix')
   ```
2. You have `gather_facts` set to `false`, but with fact gathering
   disabled Ansible won't provide you with any facts. You need to
   enable fact gathering if you want Ansible to provide you with
   information about host interfaces.
3. I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do in your `check local mac` task, but this seems to accomplish what you were asking about:

   ```
   - hosts: localhost
     gather_facts: true
     vars_prompt:
       - name: "MACADDRESS"
         prompt: "mac address?(please use Unix format ex- 1a:2b:3c:4d:5e:6f )"
         private: no

     tasks:
       - name: check macaddresssyntax
         fail:
           msg: "Invalid mac address syntax"
         when: not MACADDRESS | ansible.utils.hwaddr('unix')

       # In this task, we loop over `ansible_interfaces`, which is
       # a list of interface names. We set the `matched_interface`
       # variable to the current interface name if it has a
       # matching MAC address.
       - name: check local mac
         set_fact:
           matched_interface: "{{ ifname }}"
         when: >-
           lookup('vars', 'ansible_{}'.format(ifname)).macaddress|default(false) == MACADDRESS
         vars:
           # For whatever reason, ansible replaces `-` in interface
           # names with `_`.
           ifname: "{{ item.replace('-', '_') }}"
         loop: "{{ ansible_interfaces }}"

       - debug:
           msg: "the interface related to {{ MACADDRESS }} is {{ matched_interface }}"
         when: matched_interface|default(false)

       - fail:
           msg: "no interfaces found with mac address {{ MACADDRESS }}"
         when: not matched_interface|default(false)
   ```

Running the above playbook on my system, which has an interface with address `a2:29:ab:4e:e7:74`, looks like this:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -e MACADDRESS='a2:29:ab:4e:e7:74
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [check macaddresssyntax] **************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [check local mac] *********************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item=veth92b9a89f) 
...
ok: [localhost] => (item=example)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=lo) 
...

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "the interface related to a2:29:ab:4e:e7:74 is example"
}

TASK [fail] ********************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=2    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

If I run it with a MAC address that doesn't exist on my system, I get:

```
TASK [check local mac] *********************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item=veth168ad56c) 
...

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [fail] ********************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "no interfaces found with mac address a2:29:ab:4e:e7:77"}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=3    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: you are just amazing this is actually what i am looking for. But while exciting the playbook it skips the interface name and  i got this error in debug task 

`
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'matched_interface' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (matched_interface): 'matched_interface' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/m/setup/macsyntax.yml': line 29, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - debug:\n      ^ here\n"} `

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot to make an edit to this answer. We need to either add a default value for `matched_interface`, or use the `default` filter whenever we reference it (I went with the second choice).

Comment: it's working like a magic now. I really appreciate it @larsks. Well done man. 
This is what i am looking for
Thank you so much

Comment: If this resolved your question, consider marking it as "accepted" by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Collect the network's facts and get the list of interfaces. For example,

```yaml
    - setup:
        gather_subset: network
    - debug:
        var: ansible_facts.interfaces
```

gives

```yaml
ansible_facts.interfaces:
  - lo0
  - lo1
  - pflog0
  - wlan0
```

Put the declaration below as [appropriate](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)

```yaml
_ifcs: "{{ ansible_facts.interfaces|map('extract', ansible_facts)|list }}"
_macs: "{{ _ifcs|json_query('[].macaddress') }}"
_devs: "{{ _ifcs|json_query('[].device') }}"
_macs_valid: "{{ _macs|map('ansible.utils.hwaddr', 'bool')|
                       map('ternary', true, false)|list }}"
_dev_mac_valid: "{{ _devs|zip(_macs)|zip(_macs_valid)|
                          map('flatten')|
                          selectattr(2) }}"
dev_mac_valid: "{{ _dev_mac_valid|map('zip', ['dev', 'mac', 'valid'])|
                                  map('map', 'reverse')|
                                  map('community.general.dict') }}"
dev_mac: "{{ dev_mac_valid|items2dict(key_name='dev', value_name='mac') }}"
mac_dev: "{{ dev_mac_valid|items2dict(key_name='mac', value_name='dev') }}"
```

For example, these evaluate to

```yaml
_macs: [unknown, unknown, unknown, '00:12:00:34:56:78']
_macs_valid: [false, false, false, true]
_devs: [lo0, lo1, pflog0, wlan0]
_dev_mac_valid:
  - [wlan0, '00:12:00:34:56:78', true]

dev_mac_valid:
  - dev: wlan0
    mac: 00:12:00:34:56:78
    valid: true

dev_mac:
  wlan0: 00:12:00:34:56:78

mac_dev:
  00:12:00:34:56:78: wlan0
```

---

Q: ***"Check if the given macaddress match an existing one in the hosts"***

A: Use the dictionary *mac_dev*. For example,

```yaml
    - pause:
        prompt: "Enter MAC address"
      register: result
    - set_fact:
        macaddress: "{{ result.user_input }}"
    - assert:
        that: macaddress|ansible.utils.hwaddr('bool')
        fail_msg: Wrong MAC address
    - assert:
        that: macaddress in mac_dev.keys()|list
        fail_msg: "No interfaces found with mac address {{ macaddress }}"
        success_msg: "Interfaces {{ mac_dev[macaddress] }} found
                      with mac address {{ macaddress }}"
```

---

If there are more hosts declare a dictionary of all hosts

```yaml
mac_dev_hosts: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|
                        zip(ansible_play_hosts|
                            map('extract', hostvars, 'mac_dev'))) }}"
```

Then, putting it all together, for example, the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: test_11,test_12,test_13
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    _ifcs: "{{ ansible_facts.interfaces|map('extract', ansible_facts)|list }}"
    _macs: "{{ _ifcs|json_query('[].macaddress') }}"
    _devs: "{{ _ifcs|json_query('[].device') }}"
    _macs_valid: "{{ _macs|map('ansible.utils.hwaddr', 'bool')|
                           map('ternary', true, false)|list }}"
    _dev_mac_valid: "{{ _devs|zip(_macs)|zip(_macs_valid)|
                              map('flatten')|
                              selectattr(2) }}"
    dev_mac_valid: "{{ _dev_mac_valid|map('zip', ['dev', 'mac', 'valid'])|
                                      map('map', 'reverse')|
                                      map('community.general.dict') }}"
    dev_mac: "{{ dev_mac_valid|items2dict(key_name='dev', value_name='mac') }}"
    mac_dev: "{{ dev_mac_valid|items2dict(key_name='mac', value_name='dev') }}"
    mac_dev_hosts: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|
                            zip(ansible_play_hosts|
                                map('extract', hostvars, 'mac_dev'))) }}"

  tasks:
    - setup:
        gather_subset: network
    - set_fact:
        mac_dev: "{{ mac_dev }}"

    - block:
        - debug:
            var: mac_dev_hosts|to_nice_yaml
        - pause:
            prompt: "Enter MAC address"
          register: result
        - set_fact:
            macaddress: "{{ result.user_input }}"
        - assert:
            that: macaddress|ansible.utils.hwaddr('bool')
            fail_msg: Wrong MAC address
        - assert:
            that: macaddress in mac_dev_hosts|json_query('*.keys(@)')|flatten
            fail_msg: "No interface found with mac address {{ macaddress }}"
        - debug:
            msg: "Interface {{ dev }} found with mac address {{ macaddress }}
                  at {{ hst }}"
          vars:
            itm: "{{ mac_dev_hosts|dict2items|
                     selectattr('value', 'contains', macaddress)|first }}"
            hst: "{{ itm.key }}"
            dev: "{{ itm.value[macaddress] }}"
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
PLAY [test_11,test_12,test_13] ***************************************************************

TASK [setup] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_13]
ok: [test_12]
ok: [test_11]

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************
ok: [test_13]
ok: [test_11]
ok: [test_12]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  mac_dev_hosts|to_nice_yaml: |-
    test_11:
        00:12:00:34:56:AA: wlan0
    test_12:
        00:12:00:34:56:BB: wlan0
    test_13:
        00:12:00:34:56:CC: wlan0

TASK [pause] *********************************************************************************
[pause]
Enter MAC address:
00:12:00:34:56:CC^Mok: [test_11]

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************
ok: [test_11]

TASK [assert] ********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => changed=false 
  msg: All assertions passed

TASK [assert] ********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => changed=false 
  msg: All assertions passed

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  msg: Interface wlan0 found with mac address 00:12:00:34:56:CC at test_13

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
test_11: ok=8    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_12: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_13: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

If the MAC is missing the play will fail, for example

```yaml
TASK [assert] ********************************************************************************
fatal: [test_11]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  assertion: macaddress in mac_dev_hosts|json_query('*.keys(@)')|flatten
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: No interface found with mac address 00:12:00:34:56:FF
```

Comment: thank you so much for the reply. It's really helpful. I found also your solution very efficient